# How to create a dynamic array name?

Tags: javascript

Been researching this and really haven't found a solution. In JavaScript, I want to be able to save an array to another array that would contain the array name (`savedArrayCreated`) plus a number (1,2,3... etc.)

For example:

```
arrayCreated[]
```

Save the `arrayCreated` to: `savedArrayCreated1`

then go back and clear `arrayCreated`, populate it with new array numbers and:

Save the `arrayCreated` to: `savedArrayCreated2`

And so on.

So the number at the end of the `savedArrayCreated` field would increase and I would be able to create an array with that name/number combination.

Comment: Why would you want that? Arrays exist, so that you _don’t_ have to start using any such “numbered variable names” nonsense … You should go with `savedArrayCreated`, and make _that_ an array _of_ arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have something like this:

```
var arrayCreated = [1,2,3,4];
var dynamicName = 'savedArrayCreated1';

window[dynamicName] = [...arrayCreated]; //copy by val not ref
console.log(eval(dynamicName)); // print [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can create variables name in js. But I think the thing which you want to achieve you can do with array of arrays, which in my opinion is much better solution. Example:

```
savedArraysCreated = []
arrayCreated = [1, 2, 3]
saveArraysCreated[0] = arrayCreated
```

But also I suggest to check this post.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign dynamically named variables to the local scope:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  var arrayCreated = [i+1,i+2,i+3]
   this["arrayCreatedSaved"+i] = arrayCreated;
}

var a = this.arrayCreatedSaved0;
var b = this.arrayCreatedSaved1;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/matt_b/wp1kof2t/2/